# Leave one lognormal data point out and approximate it with columnwise expectation value + variance

Tags: r

If my data is normal distributed, i can generate fake data when i leave one data point out and approximate it with columnwise expected value and variance of the other data points like this.

```
a <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df) {
            
            a <- rbind(a,mvrnorm(1,colMeans(df[-c(i),]),var(df[-c(i),])))        
        }
```

How can i also do this for lognormal distributed data?